# Is it necessary to inherit System.Windows.Application base class for WPF Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

In VS2015, when we generated new WPF project, it contains App.xaml(.cs). I suppose that it will be an entry point of WPF application. Then `App.xaml.cs` becomes like:

```
...
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
    }
}
```

Now, I remove inheritance of `System.Windows.Application`,  still it seems to be working...

```
- public partial class App : Application
+ public partial class App
```

So let me ask: `App` class does not need to inherit `System.Windows.Application`? What is the difference?

thanks.

Comment: [Reading documentation may help you understand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not required. In your code you have the class defined as `partial`, this allows your code and autogenerated code by the compiler to be combined.

In your App.xaml you have

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App" ...
```

This tells the compiler you are creating a object of type `Application` with the name `WpfApplication.App` so the auto-generated code will include the inherited type class. Once your `WpfApplication.App` code is combined with the auto-generated `WpfApplication.App` the inheritance is already defined.